# is it possible to parse a big file xml with logstash

Tags: xml, logstash

I've been trying out a logstash config file for a pretty large xml-file containing log events. Thanks to the help of someon on here it originally worked, but only for a smaller version of the file. this is my log.conf

```
filter {
  xml {
    source => "message"
    store_xml => false
    xpath => [
      "//animal/name/text()", "name",
      "//animal/age/text()", "age",
      "//information/first[animal/text()=' %{name} ']/garden/text()", "garden",
      "//information/first[animal/text()=' %{name} ']/food/text()", "food"
    ]
  }
}
```

so is logstash work for huge lines of xml or is there another solutions i can use

Comment: Instead of using "//...", ie. search everywhere, it is better to specify explicit XPath expression starting from the root.